# Search only the blog area of SharePoint

Tags: search

I know searching the site-wide facility allows you to search the blog as well, but I am using the SP blog as a way of feeding a knowledge management system. The search facility added as a webpart on the page will search various sources (eg: bing, shared documents folder, etc), but I would also like to search the blog facility.

Is there a way of doing this?

addition:

I also realise that SP stores its data in a database and I guess I'd be able to interrogate that to obtain the blog content.

Does anyone know where the database is located? Currently I am using SharePoint Foundation locally on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would [create a search scope](http://sharepointsearch.com/cs/blogs/sanjaya/archive/2009/04/07/sharepoint-search-scopes-part2.aspx) to manage that. A web address scope rule maybe enough,

but to be sure I would put in a property query on ContentClass or create a new search property for ContentType (the default one includes the content type/mime type of the document e.g. "application/pdf").

Use SharePointManager and the [Search Service Tool](http://sharepointsearchserv.codeplex.com/) until you get back the right mix of url/properties to limit your results.

Comment: thanks for that. It would be useful to follow your instruction to create a custom search from within SharePoint.
BUT I wish to search SharePoint blog and shared documents from an asp.net application which is external to SharePoint itself.

This is the reason I asked for guidance on the location of the SharePoint Database so that I can write a custom stored procedure to search the Blog and Shared Documents content.

Does anyone know how I'd go about this?